# ¿Como hacer un post desde Express que me devuelva un Json con las variables ingresadas en un formulario?

Tags: nodejs, express, pug

Hola a todos y gracias por la ayuda!

Tengo el siguiente problema y soy nuevo en Express, es para un proyecto del trabajo.

Lo que necesito es hacer un post desde un formulario y que la respuesta sea un JSON con los datos ingresados en el formulario.

Estoy usando Express y Pug para el front-end.

Mi formulario Pug:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
 head
   title HPI
 body
   h1 Formulario HPI
  #container
   form(action="***.**.**.1*:12***/search" method="post")
   label(for='nodoHpi') Nodo Hpi
   input#nodoHpi(name='nodoHpi', type='text')
   br
   br
   label(for='nombreIndice') Nombre Indice
   input#nombreIndice(name='nombreIndice', type='text')
   br
   br
   label(for='valorIndice') Valor Indice
   input#valorIndice(name='valorIndice', type='text')
   br
   br
   button(type="submit") ENVIAR
```

Mi app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const hostname = '***.**.**.**:12***/search';
const port = '3000';

app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('index');
});

app.post('***.**.**.**:12***/search', (req, res) => {
    // necesito que la respuesta de este post me devuelva un JSON con los datos ingresados en el formulario
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("The server is listening in localhost: `${port}`");
});
```

Este es un ejemplo del JSON que se desea devolver, pero hay datos que son variables (que son los ingresados por el user en el form):

```
{
    "token": "1",
    "query": [{
        "index": "ALTC.MC_ROBERTS",
        "terms": [{
            "name": "INDEXTEXT01T",
            "value": "3044071*",
            "operator": "like"
        }],
        "results": {
            "count": 5000,
            "sort": [{
                "name": "ISSUE_DATE",
                "order": "descending"
            }],
            "fields": []
        }
    }]
}
```

donde

**ALTC.MC_ROBERTS

INDEXTEXT01T

3044071**

Son datos variables.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas utilizar `body-parser` en tu servidor:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const port = '3000';

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)

  console.log(req.body.nodoHpi)
  console.log(req.body.nombreIndice)
  console.log(req.body.valorIndice)
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The server is listening in localhost: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: El body-parser es para parsear la respuesta en formato JSON ... lo que estoy necesitando es saber como hacer la petición por post !